# Vim style cursor movement for Notepad++

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, text-editors

I was just wondering if there was a way to get "vim" style cursor movement (i.e. 'hkjl' movement). After spending much time with vim, I have gotten used to not having to lift my hands off the keyboard to move around a text document (going to the arrow keys is also too disruptive :p).

Moving back to vim is always an option, but it'd be nice if there was a way to get this feature on notepad++. I have already spent some time in setting up macros and plugins to get my notepad++ environment working the way I want it to.

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A new plugin [ViSimulator for Notepad++](https://sourceforge.net/projects/notepadplugin/files/ViSimulator%20for%20Notepad%2B%2B/)
has just released, which maybe meet your requests.

Comment: I know you'll never hear this comment, but maybe you should disclose your affiliation to this service...

Comment: @Ooker Their name is literally visimulator

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ is not a modal editor, how would you expect it to work? How could NP++ make the difference between a `j` for moving down one line and the `j` in `Beetlejuice`?

That's the core difference between modeless editors and modal editors: in the *normal* mode of a modal editor, you have the whole keyboard at your disposal for lightning quick operation while modeless editors only allow you to use all those alpha keys *with* modifiers.

I don't think `hjkl` is either practical or even doable in NP++. Maybe a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> combo… but that would defeat your purpose almost completely.

I might add that `hjkl` is definetely not the alpha and omega of productivity: <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> is just as silly as <kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd>, even if you keep the key down for as long as it takes. OK your hands are still on the home row but that's still a *very* inefficient way to move. Using counts (`7j`) is better, using search (`/foo`) is even better and text objects/motions are unvaluable. How would it be possible to "port" the concept of count to a modeless editor? Search is possible, of course, because it's modal in every editor and there's no way around it. What about text objects and motions?

Comment: It is indeed not a modal editor by default, so I maybe should have clarified and asked how one might simulate vim style modal editing in npp.
I am also not concerned with knowing the productivity of hjkl vs up down left right, though you are probably right in saying there are more productive ways to traverse a text document.

Comment: If you are serious about it, you should get in touch with the people behind NP++: it's open source and they are probably eager to have more commiters.

Comment: +1 for bringing the difference between two types. Speaking of productivity, what should I do if I just need to read a text file?